# Average force on the walls of the 1D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

Source: Y K Lim, Problems and Solutions in Quantum Mechanics, 1014

The average force on the walls of the 1-D box is
$$
\vec{F} = -\bigg\langle{\frac{\partial H}{\partial a}}\bigg\rangle
$$

Differentiating the equation of a stationary state $(H - E_n) \psi_n = 0$, we have
$$
\bigg( \frac{\partial H}{\partial a} - \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial a} \bigg) \psi_n + (h - E_n) \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} = 0
$$

and hence,
$$
\psi_n^* (H - E_n) \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} = \psi_n^* \bigg( \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial a} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial a} \bigg) \psi_n
$$

Integrating the left-hand side of the above, we have
$$
\int \psi_n^* (H - E_n) \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} \, dx = \int \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} (H - E_n)^* \psi_n^* \, dx
$$

which is zero, since $H$ is real.

I didn't understand this argument, why $H$ being real results in whole expression to be zero.

From this the author derives, 
$$
\bigg\langle \frac{\partial H}{\partial a} \bigg\rangle = \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial a} 
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be clearer if you write your second to last line in bra-ket notation:

$$
\langle \psi_n | H - E_n|\frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} \rangle =
\langle\psi_n| E_n - E_n | \frac{\partial \psi_n}{\partial a} \rangle = 0
$$
where in the first equality we used the fact that H is hermitian so $\langle\psi_n| H = \langle\psi_n| E_n$